# Update Dataflow Streaming job with Session and Siding window embedded in DF

Tags: google-cloud-platform, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In my use-case, I'm performing Session as well as Sliding window inside Dataflow job. So basically my Sliding window timing is 10 hour with sliding time 4 min. Since I'm applying grouping and performing max function on top of that, on every 3 min interval, window will fire the pane and it will go into Session window with triggering logic on it. Below is the code for the same.

```
Window<Map<String, String>> windowMap = Window.<Map<String, String>>into(
                SlidingWindows.of(Duration.standardHours(10)).every(Duration.standardMinutes(4)));

        Window<Map<String, String>> windowSession = Window
                .<Map<String, String>>into(Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardHours(10))).discardingFiredPanes()
                .triggering(Repeatedly
                        .forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(5))))
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(10));
```

I would like to add logger on some steps for Debugging, so I'm trying to update the current streaming job using below code:

```
options.setRegion("asia-east1");
options.setUpdate(true);
options.setStreaming(true);
```

So previously I had around 10k data and I updated the existing pipeline using above config and now I'm not able to see that much data in steps of updated DF job. So help me with the understanding whether it preserves the previous job data or not as I'm not seeing previous DF step count in updated Job.

Comment: Hello! Which version of Dataflow are you using? Do you use only "Region", "Update", "Streaming" from options?

Comment: By data do you mean the "in-flight" data in the pipeline when it updated? According to [the guide to updating Dataflow jobs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/updating-a-pipeline#preventing_compatibility_breaks) it's possible that the updated pipeline isn't compatible with the old one. Particularly if you changed the region when setting it to "asia-east1".